# [longjmp/setjmp]c++ same code windows got exception linux no error and run well

Tags: c++, linux, windows, exception

### 代码(code)

```
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

jmp_buf jb1;
jmp_buf jb2;

auto bar() {
  if (setjmp(jb2) == 0) {
    longjmp(jb1, 1);
  } else {
    longjmp(jb1, 2);
  }
}

void foo() {
  bar();
}

void testjmp() {
  auto i = setjmp(jb1);
  if (i == 0) {
    foo();
  } else {
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
  }

  i = setjmp(jb1);
  if (i == 0) {
    longjmp(jb2, -1);
  } else {
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  testjmp();
  return 0;
}
```

### windows 结果(window result)

[windows结果(windows result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0uw.png)
在Windows平台下结果表现为异常。
I got a exception at windows platform

### linux 结果(linux result)

[linux结果(linux result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOj4f.png)
在Linux平台下没有任何问题
It runs well at linux platform

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify it, which is better than adding comments. Also, replace the images with text. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Lastly, there are a few subdomains of stackoverflow (ru., es.) that don't use English as language. Maybe there's one that you could use your language, but here, please stay with English.

Comment: Don't use `setjmp()/longjmp()` in C++. Use exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second `longjmp(jb2, -1);` is invalid by sense because you try jmp to stack **bellow** then current - back to bar() which stack already overwritten, after we return to  `testjmp()`. this is of course error. so windows doing right when raise `STATUS_BAD_STACK` - *An invalid or unaligned stack was encountered during an unwind operation.* and linux do wrong here.